# Creating a dataframe structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id|c1|c2|c3|c4...
0|s:1,g:B,r:2|s:2,g:A,r:3|s:1,g:C,r:4|s:3,g:D,r:2.....
1|NaN|s:2;g:E,r:4|s:3;g:C,r:3|s:3;g:F,r:3.....
```

I want to rearrange the dataframe like this:

```
id|c|s|g|r
0|c1|1|B|2
0|c2|2|A|3
0|c3|1|C|4
0|c4|3|D|2
1|c1|NaN|NaN|NaN
1|c2|2|E|4
1|c3|3|C|3
1|c4|3|F|3
```

I have tried the following:

```
df.melt()
```

Comment: if possible share code snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with[`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and replace missing values by empty columns names `s,g,r`, then [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `;` or `,`, again reshape, then split by `:` and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('id')
         .fillna('s,g,r')
         .stack()
         .str.split(',|;', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .str.split(':', expand=True)
         .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
         .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis(('id','c'))
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .reset_index()
         )
print (df1)
   id   c     g     r     s
0   0  c1     B     2     1
1   0  c2     A     3     2
2   0  c3     C     4     1
3   0  c4     D     2     3
4   1  c1  None  None  None
5   1  c2     E     4     2
6   1  c3     C     3     3
7   1  c4     F     3     3
```

EDIT: First step is reshape by `stack` with index `id`:

```
print (df.set_index('id')
         .fillna('s,g,r')
         .stack())
id    
0   c1    s:1,g:B,r:2
    c2    s:2,g:A,r:3
    c3    s:1,g:C,r:4
    c4    s:3,g:D,r:2
1   c1          s,g,r
    c2    s:2;g:E,r:4
    c3    s:3;g:C,r:3
    c4    s:3;g:F,r:3
dtype: object
```

Next step is spit by separator and again reshape by `stack`:

```
print (df.set_index('id')
         .fillna('s,g,r')
         .stack()
         .str.split(',|;', expand=True)
         .stack())
id       
0   c1  0    s:1
        1    g:B
        2    r:2
    c2  0    s:2
        1    g:A
        2    r:3
    c3  0    s:1
        1    g:C
        2    r:4
    c4  0    s:3
        1    g:D
        2    r:2
1   c1  0      s
        1      g
        2      r
    c2  0    s:2
        1    g:E
        2    r:4
    c3  0    s:3
        1    g:C
        2    r:3
    c4  0    s:3
        1    g:F
        2    r:3
dtype: object
```

Then split by `:` to 2 columns and convert first column to last level of `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df.set_index('id')
         .fillna('s,g,r')
         .stack()
         .str.split(',|;', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .str.split(':', expand=True)
         .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
         .set_index(0, append=True)[1])
id      0
0   c1  s       1
        g       B
        r       2
    c2  s       2
        g       A
        r       3
    c3  s       1
        g       C
        r       4
    c4  s       3
        g       D
        r       2
1   c1  s    None
        g    None
        r    None
    c2  s       2
        g       E
        r       4
    c3  s       3
        g       C
        r       3
    c4  s       3
        g       F
        r       3
```

Last reshape by `unstack`:

```
print (df.set_index('id')
         .fillna('s,g,r')
         .stack()
         .str.split(',|;', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .str.split(':', expand=True)
         .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
         .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
         .unstack())
0         g     r     s
id                     
0  c1     B     2     1
   c2     A     3     2
   c3     C     4     1
   c4     D     2     3
1  c1  None  None  None
   c2     E     4     2
   c3     C     3     3
   c4     F     3     3
```

Comment: It worked but I am getting both nan and None.What does both of them mean?for example,array(['2', '1', None, '3', '4', 'Other', nan], dtype=object).Instead I want all as nan

Comment: @SriTest - I think no problem if `None` and `NaN`, pandas working with it same way. But if wat replace `None` to `NaN`s use `df = df.mask(df.isna(), np.nan)` after my solution

Comment: Thats a new one for me. Great!It works fine.But would you try to explain me what approach you have taken like in steps.That would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and `stack` with `series.str.split`

```
df = df.set_index('id')
(df.stack(dropna=False).str.split(',|;').explode().str.split(':',expand=True)
.set_index(0,append=True)[1].unstack().dropna(how='all',axis=1)
.rename_axis(['id','C']).reset_index())
```

---

```
0  id   C    g    r    s
0   0  c1    B    2    1
1   0  c2    A    3    2
2   0  c3    C    4    1
3   0  c4    D    2    3
4   1  c1  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   1  c2    E    4    2
6   1  c3    C    3    3
7   1  c4    F    3    3
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode' . I get this exception

Comment: @SriTest `explode` is available from pandas version `0.25` and above. you have to upgrade the pandas version for explode to be available

Answer (score 1):

I will suggested

```
s=df.melt('id')
s.loc[s.value.notna(),'value']=[dict(item.split(":") for item in x.replace(';',',').split(",")) for x in s.value.dropna()]
s=s.join(pd.DataFrame(s.value.dropna().tolist(),index=s.dropna().index))
```

Comment: Throws an exception like AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'